# program for printing 'Square' pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

I have tried printing 3*5 box `*` (star) pattern program, but not able to get it to format properly. Can any one guide me mistakes if and help to rectify?

Below is the javascript code:

```
// Getting input via STDIN
const readline = require("readline");

const inp = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin
});

const userInput = [];

inp.on("line", (data) => {
  userInput.push(data);
});

inp.on("close", () => {
  //start-here
var i,j,a=3,b=5;
for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=b;j++)
    {
        console.log("*");
    }

    console.log("\n");

}

  //end-here
});
```

output:

```
*
*
*
*
*

*
*
*
*
*

*
*
*
*
*
```

need to get like this output:

```
*****
*****
*****
```

Comment: Why are you taking input from stdin?

Answer (score 5):

`console.log` automatically logs to a new line. You should instead append to a variable and log it outside of the loop:

```js
var i, j, a = 3,
  b = 5;
for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
  var str = "";
  for (j = 1; j <= b; j++) {
    str += "*";
  }
  console.log(str + "\n");
}
```

Or even better, don't use a loop at all and use [`String.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

```js
var i, j, a = 3,
  b = 5;
for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
  console.log("*".repeat(b) + "\n");
}
```